# cannot import *d.ts on node project

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql

I have the following code structure:

```
src
├── config
│   └── index.ts
├── db
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── Schema.json
├── graphql
│   ├── resolvers.ts
│   └── schema.graphql
├── index.ts
└── models
    ├── graphql.d.ts
    └── index.d.ts
```

the problem is what when try to import modes on resolvers.ts with the following code:

```
import {IPhoto} from '../models'
```

I get the following options:

> Error: Cannot find module '../models'

The tsconfig.json is the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
"include": ["src/**/*", "src/scripts", "package.json", "types/**/*", "src/scripts/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    ".cache",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "build",
    "coverage",
    "jest.config.js",
    "jest",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

in order to launch this I use the following script:

```
"dev": "env-cmd tsnd --respawn src/index.ts",
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't models a folder and not a js/ts file?